# Minimizing redundancy of MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to reduce the redundancy of a query in MySQL. I currently have it working, but it feels like I have too much overhead because it uses a redundant subquery. What I am trying to do is use a dvd rental database to find which store location has rented out more dvd's for each month in 2005.

Here is the working query

```
SELECT b.month, c.store_id, b.maxRentals
FROM
    (SELECT a.month, MAX(a.rentalCount) as maxRentals
    FROM
        (SELECT MONTH(rental.rental_date) as month, inventory.store_id, count(1) as rentalCount
        FROM rental

        INNER JOIN inventory
        ON rental.inventory_id = inventory.inventory_id

        WHERE YEAR(rental.rental_date) = 2005

        GROUP BY MONTH(rental.rental_date), inventory.store_id
        ) a
    GROUP BY a.month
    ) b

    INNER JOIN

    (SELECT MONTH(rental.rental_date) as month, inventory.store_id, count(1) as rentalCount
    FROM rental

    INNER JOIN inventory
    ON rental.inventory_id = inventory.inventory_id

    WHERE YEAR(rental.rental_date) = 2005

    GROUP BY MONTH(rental.rental_date), inventory.store_id
    ) c
ON b.maxRentals = c.rentalCount

GROUP BY b.month;
```

Notice how the subquery with the alias of "c" is the exact same subquery of alias "a". I'm not sure if there's a way to get rid of this, as I can't inner join on an alias. Am I just stuck with a giant query, or is there something else I can do?

Comment: MySQL 8 (currently in beta) will implement Common Table Expressions, so you will be able to do this in the future with less redundancy. Or you could switch to PostgreSQL or any other SQL database.

Comment: How about `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS invent AS (SELECT [subquery SQL here])`, then join to `invent` (and drop at the end)?

Comment: Now looking at your code, I think it can be re-written using `CASE`... let me have a go...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am 90% certain this query will achieve your intentions:

```
SELECT MONTH(r.rental_date), i.store_id, COUNT(*)
FROM rental r
LEFT JOIN inventory i ON r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
WHERE YEAR(r.rental_date) = 2005
GROUP BY MONTH(r.rental_date), i.store_id
```

Let me know how it goes!

**Edit:** to answer the question *which store location has rented out more dvd's for each month in 2005*:

```
SELECT x.rental_month, x.store_id, MAX(x.rental_count) FROM (
SELECT MONTH(r.rental_date) AS rental_month, i.store_id AS store_id, COUNT(*) AS rental_count
FROM rental r LEFT JOIN inventory i ON r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
WHERE YEAR(r.rental_date) = 2005
GROUP BY MONTH(r.rental_date), i.store_id) x
GROUP BY x.rental_month, x.store_id
```

I was explicit by using aliases everywhere, you could probably omit some. Hopefully this helps...

**Edit:** Dirty hack:

```
SELECT x.rental_month, x.store_id, MAX(x.rental_count) FROM (
SELECT MONTH(r.rental_date) AS rental_month, i.store_id AS store_id, COUNT(*) AS rental_count
FROM rental r LEFT JOIN inventory i ON r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
WHERE YEAR(r.rental_date) = 2005
GROUP BY MONTH(r.rental_date), i.store_id
ORDER BY MONTH(r.rental_date) ASC, COUNT(*) DESC) x
GROUP BY x.rental_month
```

Ref:
http://kristiannielsen.livejournal.com/6745.html

But then does this satisfy you, seeing as you do already have a working query...

Comment: This query is the same as my subqueries a & c. This would be correct if it only returned the month, store, and count for the store with the most rentals per month, which is what i'm trying to achieve above. Technically, you are indeed able to easily tell which store rented more per month from this table, but is not exactly what I need the query to do.

Comment: Ah, I just posted an edit in the meantime, but let me read your comment to see if it addresses it...

Comment: I believe the edit addresses the comment and intention?

Comment: by using x.store_id in the group by clause, this query returns the exact same result as the first. Without it, however, will return the Months and maximum rental count, but the incorrect store.

Comment: I'm starting to think no matter which way the problem is addressed, the query will probably end up being about as big as what I posted

Comment: Oh.. sorry. But the store is incorrect? Really? Do you have quick sample data? I really think the OP is too long for something relatively trivial.

Comment: See my edit, although are you looking for shorter code or faster execution?

Comment: Just looking for shorter code. That order by is very clever! Appreciate all the work you threw at this.

Comment: Thanks, it's a very interesting problem, the link does a good job talking through solutions and their timings.